# Ubuntu - Upstart with a python script that start and finish their own processes

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, init

I'm trying to setup with Upstart a python script that launch several internal procs and kill them if is required with this sentences:

```
$ listener.py -startall
$ listener.py -killall
```

My Upstart file:

```
# Listener Service

description     "Listener Server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

exec /home/www-data/listener/bin/listener.py -startall

pre-stop        exec /home/www-data/listener/bin/listener.py -killall
```

I'm wondering how use the python script command in order to finish the service, if I try to stop with :

```
$ sudo service listener stop
$ stop: Unknown instance:
```

Its fails, my upstart file only start the services but doesn't work when I try to stop it.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking the plymouth.conf example I add to my upstart script a sentence to mark the service like a process that fork more procs: expect fork

```
# Listener Service

description     "Listener Server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

expect fork

exec /home/www-data/listener/bin/listener.py -startall

pre-stop        exec /home/www-data/listener/bin/listener.py -killall
```

Now all is working fine..